# Angular base href dynamically

Tags: iis-7, href, angular6, radix

We have two environments: Development & Production

Let's say we have one page with route URL segment: order/sales/all

**PRODUCTION** URL:

```
http://www.example.com/order/sales/all
```

Set `<base href="/">` & in app.module.ts set [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }

**DEVELOPMENT** is hosted on local IIS.

Assume that more than 2 people are working into their own branch.

User1 url: `http://localhost/test1/order/sales/all`

User2 url: `http://localhost/test2/order/sales/all`

User3 url: `http://localhost/test3/order/sales/all`

How can I set the virtual path test1, test2, test3 or anything to my Angular routing?

If I set into `<base href="/test1/">` then every user has to add their own branch, which is not preferable.

Is there any way to read the virtual path and set it to base href dynamically?

or any other alternative way that we can ignore test1, test2, test3 for routing?

Thanks.